# How do i tweak my blogger page to my taste for effective blogging experience

Tags: blog

I have been blogging for over one year with blogger but I personally don't feel its user friendly as WordPress, but I don't want to move my contents or blog to wordpress. How do I tweak blogger to my taste?

Comment: Is your question about writing? It seems to be about how to make your Blogger layout more user-friendly. And if that's the case, this isn't the right place for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about writing, but instead appears to be about blog design.

Comment: Agreed. Unless there's something content-related you're having trouble doing, this is mostly just something you'll need to read Blogger's documentation for, and see if  it's flexible enough for what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Tweak what you know how to do.  If you don't want to change the site then change things you are able to.  Backgrounds, images, color schemes, a lot of that is usually easily changed in template websites like blogger, wordpress, wix and so on.  If it has advanced HTML options for you to do custom coding, do some googling to see if anything is already pre-done to your tastes.  There are thousands of these types of pages all over the internet.  I am sure you can find a custom template out there for free that you can tweak to your tastes as well and upload it to the html area.

You can also try finding any guides and/or youtube videos to see if anyone has maybe some basic set up tips that will help you get through the user friendliness issue.

You may want to figure out though if the research time and implementation time to make these tweaks in blogger is worth staying when for equal or slightly more/less time you can port everything over to wordpress with the customization you want.  If you are going to spend all weekend playing around with HTML code for a better layout or spend all weekend porting everything and have full customization of what you want, which would you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress (especially self-hosted)
is infinitely more customizable than Blogger, so it is tough to suggest a plausible compromise. If you are categorically against use of the platform which powers up quarter of the internet sites, I would suggest to pick a Blogger theme you do not hate and concentrate on your content, while slowly tweaking the theme to your liking.

Eventually It is your content your readers are interested in, not the color scheme and the bells and whistles.